# Docker EC2 & port binding

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, docker, amazon-ec2

I have an Ubuntu EC2 instance. Have current version of Docker installed.

Running a [Jenkins container](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jenkins/) on the EC2 host.

The Docker run command I am using is:

```
docker run \
-d \
-p 9000:8080 \
-p 5000:5000 \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
jenkinsci/jenkins
```

The command completes successfully and my container has started.

If I SSH into the EC2 instance `curl` the container like:

```
curl http://localhost:9000
```

I get a response.

If I try the same via the EC2 instance public IP address:

```
curl http://55.55.55.55:9000
```

I don't get a response.

The EC2 instance security group has `9000` open to anywhere and I can confirm it's accepting connections on `9000` by doing:

```
telnet 55.55.55.55 9000
```

Which is able to connect.

So my guess is, it seems the instance is accepting connections on `9000` but these aren't being passed through to Docker.

In the Dockerfile I can see `EXPOSE` commands for Jenkins default ports `8080` and `5000`. Could this be an issue when I'm binding `9000`?

Any ideas or debugging is much appreciated, has me stumped currently!

Should also point out, binding the container to `8080` is not an option unfortunately.

**UPDATE**

Local curl response:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/>
<script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script>
</head>
<body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>
Authentication required
</body></html>
```

`docker ps` output:

```
56c3ad9f1085        
jenkinsci/jenkins   
"/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   
About an hour ago   
Up About an hour    
0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 50000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->8080/tcp   
jenkins
```

`iptables -L -n` output

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:5000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

`tcpdump` available here: https://gist.github.com/timothyclifford/f9b51d5528dbe74f491bb7c35153c667

Comment: Normally your setup should work. Port 9000 is open you said, it's http (tcp)?.

Comment: Yes the instance has a security group with `9000` open to `Anywhere`

Comment: 5000 too? and what is the output of the curl to localhost? Something like this? `<title>Jenkins [Jenkins]</title><link rel="stylesheet" hr..` + can I see the whole output of docker ps command for that jenkins container.

Comment: Have added `curl` output and `docker ps` output

Comment: Also added `iptables` output

Comment: Have you tried to stick on 8080? `-p 8080:8080` maybe jenkins is trying to do a redirect to the 8080 port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, found the issue was related to internal network.

Very strange behaviour!

To anyone seeing similar issues, my suggestion would be to test as many variables as possible - different network / host / location.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit weird .. particularly that telnet is able to connect but curl is not.  (If it wasn't for that bit, then I might say it could be an iptables thing?) Normally, I'd reach for tcpdump .. presumably curl is able to establish a TCP connection (same as telnet) but I can't see why the HTTP layer would fail then.  Install tcpdump on your ubuntu box, then run this as root:

```
tcpdump -nn port 9000
```

You could also try issuing an HTTP request using telnet and see if that works .... From your telnet connection, just type in something like

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 55.55.55.55:9000
```

then hit enter a couple of times. You should get an HTTP response back.  You could try this against e.g. google to make sure you understand what should happen here:

```
# telnet www.google.com 80
Trying 216.58.212.132...
Connected to www.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=rfP9V_P9M8_G8AeSsrWwBw
Content-Length: 261
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 08:26:21 GMT

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=rfP9V_P9M8_G8AeSsrWwBw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Update: from your tcpdump output, it looks like it's the return path that could be the problem here.  `Flags [S.]` is the SYN-ACK back from the handshake. Can you tcpdump on your local box to see if you get that packet? I don't think you'd need to open the outbound ports .. the firewall/security group should see this as the response flow, so I'm a little confused, but at least you can see the initial packet arrive.  Thinking....

Comment: Get a response from your Google example. When trying with my host, get no response, just hangs...

Comment: Updated with local dump

Comment: Added gist with tcpdump from local/host on same request

Comment: Huh, weird!  You're getting the TCP handshake setup, and presumably your local client is sending the request and the server gets it, but the server is having a hard time delivering the response.  Be good to confirm that using "tcpdump -nn -s0 -A port 9000" on server and local.  You should see the GET on the server, and the response being sent from server multiple times, but no response on the "local" client.  Very confused by that...  Best I can think is it's some weird fireballing rule on your local system that's trapped it.

Comment: Possibly, but then it's odd that I can connect to another EC2 instance on port 900, in the same environment, same security groups etc from my local!